# Page Lifecycle and Asynchronous Requests in C# asp.net web forms

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, httpwebrequest, asynchronous

If I send an HttpWebRequest and send it out with BeginGetResponse with a callback, my callback never gets hit. THe page finishes before the response is given.

How do I grab the response?

I have tried setting a timer:

```
  ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(result.AsyncWaitHandle, new WaitOrTimerCallback(TimeoutCallback), null, DefaultTimeout, true);
```

but again if DefaultTimeout (in milliseonds) is set to 1 millisecond, it reaches the callback. But if it is set to 30 seconds, then the callback never gets fired.

How do I access the request/result again?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to wait for the web request to complete before allowing your code to continue executing, you'll need to use the synchronous [GetResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse.aspx) method instead of the asynchronous [BeginGetResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetresponse.aspx) method. This will block the current thread until the request completes.

Comment: i don't want to wait for it. what i want is it to go fire by itself and another event (clicking another button) to check if its done